# how to add external js in HTMLField of djangocms_text_ckeditor

Tags: python-3.x, ckeditor, django-cms, djangocms-text-ckeditor

I am using the djangocms in my project and I wanted to have some custom changes for that I need to add some js and css files in HTMLField of the djangocms_text_ckeditor. I found the documentation for adding the css links in the setting.py, which is as follows:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS = {
    'contentsCss': ['/static/css/base.css'],
}
```

But not know to add the js file in HTMLField of the djangocms_text_ckeditor. Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Look, I found [this](https://github.com/divio/django-cms-demo/blob/7a104acaa749c52a8ed4870a74898e38daf20e46/src/settings.py#L318-L324) in the source code.